Measuring the average distance of line inside polygon in QGIS

The image is about a determinate area of study, and the line routes of the metro, and I want to know if there is a practical method to know the average distance of the line of each part of the polygon, like the average distance to one person to travel to the route?

Average distance measured in a straight line? The ~orange polygon is one polygon or multiple?

What does "each part of the polygon" mean in practical terms here? A polygon has an indefinite number of points... What exactly do you want to find out?

the orange  polygon its one area to use as a reference, and when i said each part, i need the average distance to travel to the routes, some representative points could be the intersections of the streets, but i need a optimal form to do that because the image only represent a small area, and i need to study a whole city, that its a lot of time to point each street intersection.
